# How to loop through all text box elements in a page source and find the names of all those text boxes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, ajax

I am writing a program which will output the number of GUI elements in a webpage if the source page is given as input and it should also output the names of all text boxes.

The code I wrote is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>My App</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
</head>
<body>
<textarea id="TextArea1"></textarea>
        <br />
        <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="submit" /></div>

    <script>
            var $textarea = $('#TextArea1'), $submit = $('#Submit1');
            $submit.click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                sourceCode = $textarea.val();
                var $searchObject = $('<div id="Searching"></div>');
                $searchObject.append($(sourceCode));


                //Search Tags


                $(function () {
                    var values = $('input[type=text]').map(function () {
                        return this.name
                    }).get()
                    alert(values);
                })

                alert("Name of text field = " + $searchObject.find('[type=text]').attr('name'));
                alert("Number of text boxes = " + $searchObject.find('[type=text]').length);
                alert("Number of Submit Buttons = " + $searchObject.find('[type=submit]').length);
                alert("Number of Telephone entry fields = " + $searchObject.find('[type=tel]').length);
                alert("Number of Password boxes = " + $searchObject.find('[type=password]').length);
                alert("Number of check boxes = " + $searchObject.find('[type=checkbox]').length);
                alert("Number of Radio buttons on page = " + $searchObject.find('[type=radio]').length);
                alert("Number of drop down lists = " + $searchObject.find('select').length);
                alert("Number of Images on page = " + $searchObject.find('img').length);
                alert("Number of Hyperlinks on page = " + $searchObject.find('a[href]').length);
                alert("Number of Buttons     = " + $searchObject.find('[type=button]').length);
                alert("Number of Date entry fields= " + $searchObject.find('[type=date]').length);
    });
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am getting the result always as 'domain' when i run this code:

```
$(function () {
                    var values = $('input[type=text]').map(function () {
                        return this.name
                    }).get()
                    alert(values);
              })
```

I am giving source code of Google signup page as input.
Can anyone help me with a code that will loop through all text boxes and list out their names?

Comment: `return this.name` If you want to get the `name` prop!

Comment: Oh sorry , that was a mistake on my part. ill update the question now. tnx

Comment: What is not working after applying earlier suggestion ?

Comment: i always get the name of the text box as 'domain' while the real name of the text box is "First name". I gave the source code of google signup page as input

Comment: Are you talking about `label` ? How does your HTML look like ?

Comment: No i am talking about the name="" property of type="text" field. When i run the code mentioned above, the output i am getting is 'domain' while the name of the text field is entirely different.

Comment: i do get the name if i run : alert("Name of text field = " + $searchObject.find('[type=text]').attr('name'));. But since i want to loop through all text boxes and list out their names, its of no use to me.

Comment: What about markup/html ? Difficult to guess things without that..

Comment: There is nothing much to it. There is just a text field in my html with a submit button. The source code will be entered in the text area and the result should be displayed as alerts when the submit button is clicked. Then there is the script tag which i have copied to my question.

Comment: How do we execute it to test without markup ?

Comment: I just added the entire code to my question. Thanks

Comment: Do you find any name attribute in provided HTML Or any `input type=text` ?

Comment: well as i said, i am giving source code of view-source:https://accounts.google.com/signup as input to the text area. I am very sure that there are lot of text fields with name attribute in it.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. I am not searching for text boxes in my own code. I want to search and find text boxes in google signup page and then find their names.

Comment: Wow! When did you mention that in your question ?

Comment: That was the whole point of having a text field. Why would i use input fields if there is no input. and i also stated the same on comments section. Please read the 4th comment.

Comment: Awesome.. So you expect people to read comments to make out meaning of the question ? `DOM api` works with the DOM present in the DOM tree.. _"That was the whole point"_ ? You must mention the whole point in question mate!

Comment: Coming back to the question, Make sure you do not want to track elements from the `iFrame`!

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I thought you went through the code in the question and it will be pretty clear what input i was giving. And i think people who gave answers below understood it right. Ill try it out and see what the result is. Thanks again for your help

Comment: There is nothing fancy about the answers provided below as they too are using DOM api and jQuery is just extension of what they have implemented in core JS... Have a good luck!

Comment: I have updated the question. Sorry again for the confusion.

Comment: What is `$(sourceCode)` ?

Comment: Also test `$searchObject.find(':input').length`

Comment: // Apply test input
$textarea.val('<div><input id="textbox1" type="text"/></div><input type="text" id="textbox2"/>');


$submit.click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  sourceCode = $textarea.val();

  // Create jQuery object to insert and search the source code (from the textarea)
  var $searchObject = $('<div id="searchThis"></div>');

  // Append the source code (converted to a jQuery object)
  $searchObject.append($(sourceCode));

  // Search the object for occurrence of type="text" inputs
  alert($searchObject.find('[type=text]').length);

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simplest most efficient:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',()=>{
    var names = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=text]').map((o)=>o.name);
    console.log(names);
});
//PROTOTYPE MODIFICATIONS
NodeList.prototype.map = HTMLCollection.prototype.map = Array.prototype.map;
```

Comment: Why ? What is wrong with the code OP has provided ? How your code is different from the one OP has provided ?

Comment: @RayonDabre now that it's been updated it does looks to be the same, it would still preform more efficient by a few milliseconds though :) being that it's shorthand and not running through jQ.

Comment: How does it answers the question ? Question was not about _"performance"_ I guess!

Comment: @RayonDabre what are you talking about.... and i quote, "Can anyone help me with a code that will loop through all text boxes and list out their names?"

Comment: Hey mat! There is provided code in the snippet... You must make out "why it is not working" and provide solution accordingly...

Comment: My point is, Why `$(function () {
                    var values = $('input[type=text]').map(function () {
                        return this.name
                    }).get()
                    alert(values);
              })` is not working ? Any guesses ?

Comment: Also read about [__"What's wrong with extending the DOM"__](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/)

Answer (score 0):

for getting name of all the input text type element, you need to loop through all text type element:

```
$searchObject.find('[type=text]').each(function() {
     alert($(this).attr("name"));
});
```

This will give you name of all the text type input elements.

Comment: Why ? What is wrong with the code OP has provided ? How your code is different from the one OP has provided ?

Answer (score 0):

```
var textBoxList={}; //object
var textBoxListARR=[] //array

$.each($("input[type='text']"),function(i,e){
    textBoxListARR.push(e.name); //create array
    textBoxList[e.id]=e.name; //create object
});

//resutls
console.log(textBoxList);
console.log(textBoxListARR);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add some explanation of why this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [answer] for more information.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body').find("input[type='text']").each(function (index) {
   //get name or anything whatever you want.

});
```

here body is the parent element